# Display SurfaceTexture created in foregroundservice to activity?

Tags: android, camera, surface

I'm using a `SurfaceTexture` which I've created in a `ForegroundService` to capture videos from the camera without any `Activity` with `SurfaceView`.

How can I display my `SurfaceTexture` in an `Activity`?

I've been looking for something like `SurfaceView.setSurfaceTexture()` or a constructor that takes a `SurfaceTexture` but I couldn't find anything.